# Can I assign a static nested class to a variable?

Tags: java, nested-class

I have a few different button layouts for some controllers mapped inside nested classes. Here's an example:

```
public class ControllerMap{
    public static class Type1{
        public static final int BUTTON_A = 1,
                                BUTTON_B = 2;
    }

    public static class Type2{
        public static final int BUTTON_A = 2,
                                BUTTON_B = 1;
    }   
}
```

I want to make a variable to reference which one to use throughout my code. Something like `layout = ControllerMap.Type1;`. I'm pretty sure this isn't actually possible, but is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: since it's public, you can already use it anywhere throughout your code. However, I think you cannot do what you are trying to do. You could keep a reference to the class but that won't let reference fields. `Class<ControllerMap.Type1> clazz = ControllerMap.Type1.class;`

Comment: Can you help us understand what you're trying to accomplish by doing this? We may be able to provide insight into a better solution.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure this isn't actually possible" - that is of course entirely made up. You can create a variable with the type `Type1` or `Type2` pretty much anywhere, you simply need to reference it correctly, either via `ControllerMap.Type1 myType;` or even via `import static ...` and `Type1 myType;`

Comment: Paul_R, I have two different controllers, each with different button layouts. I need to be able to easily change which one I'm using during runtime. It's also useful for me to be able to change what buttons do what actions (ex. A on one controller will do something different from A on the other).

Comment: specializt, I am able to reference each individual layout like that, but am I able to assign it to a variable such that I could switch between them during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to be used as layout templates, you could do something like this:

```
public class Template
{
    public static final Template type1 = new Template(1, 2);
    public static final Template type2 = new Template(2, 1);

    public int buttonA;
    public int buttonB;

    public Template(int buttonA, int buttonB)
    {
        this.buttonA = buttonA;
        this.buttonB = buttonB;
    }
}
```

And then you can use the `layout` variable like this:

```
public static Template layout = Template.type1;
```

Comment: This works, but I have 16 constants I need to define for each controller, so that would make it a pain to have to go back and change anything.

Comment: Still this is shorter than having 16 different classes. Using this technique, you would have 1 line per template, and 16 lines *once* at the `Template` class definition, one for each constant.

Comment: Ah, I think you misunderstood me. I meant I have 16 buttons/axes to define per template, I probably only need like 4 templates. I'll probably end up using this though. It may not be as easy to read/edit, but at least it'll let me change it during runtime. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could refer it from anywhere since both your class are public and class variables are public too like:

```
int button = ControllerMap.Type1.BUTTON_A;//from anywhere and is resolved at compile time
```

But if you need it runtime, you could just inject appropriate instance and create getter/setter instead of exposing the field directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use 'static' in an OO way which will never work. In this case you can use the Strategy Pattern to solve your issue, but you will have to adapt your code.

Make your class Type1 and Type2 implement a interface (iController). Then anywhere in your code you can can assign:

```
iController controller = new Type1();
```

Comment: what makes you think `static` "will never work" inside of an OO application? Could it be that you're new to all of these things?

Comment: Well as far as I understood he wants to have a reference to 'a' static Type without knowing which implementation is behind it. This is a OO concept and can't work with static types where everything is defined on class level no?

Comment: ... wrong. He can simply use interfaces, generics or even class-casting, pretty much everything is possible. Personally, i would recommend interfaces combined with generics - that way he will even be able to implement dynamic sub-types and use lambda inside of factories, for example

Comment: It just depends if he want to switch his `layout` reference to a different controller type implementation or not, which is not really defined in the question.